# Best way to do getView on ListAdapter to minimize garbage collection

Tags: android, garbage-collection, listadapter

I've made a CustomListAdapater which works fine, however, I get quite a few garbage collection messages popping up when I scroll through the list quickly.

Is there a best practice to making a efficient custom ListAdapter?

Here's what I have t the moment what works, but isn't great.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout centreView;
    //Get the current alert object

    if (convertView == null) {
        centreView = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi.inflate(resource, centreView, true);
    }
    else
    {
        centreView = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_name);
    TextView venue = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_venue);
    TextView time = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_time);
    TextView room = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_room);
    TextView id = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_id);
    TextView dayTV = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_day);
    TextView desc = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_description);
    TextView json = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_json);

    String timeString;
    try {
        JSONObject thisRow = items.get(position);
        name.setText(thisRow.getString("className"));

        dayTV.setText(thisRow.getString("theDate"));
        json.setText(thisRow.toString());
        venue.setText(thisRow.getString("venue"));
        final String ID = thisRow.getString("id");
        id.setText(ID);


        desc.setText(thisRow.getString("description"));


        timeString = thisRow.getString("startTime");
        timeString += " - "+thisRow.getString("endTime");
        time.setText(timeString);



        room.setText(thisRow.getString("room"));


        final Button alter = (Button) centreView.findViewById(R.id.is_alt);
        alter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final JSONArray alterations = thisRow.getJSONArray("alteration");

        if (alterations.getJSONObject(0).getString("show").equals("yes")) {
            alter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            alter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ActivityViewTimetable actVT = (ActivityViewTimetable) getContext();
                    actVT.showAlterations(alterations);
                }
            });
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("FUApp", "JSON Error (TimetableItemsArrayAdapter): " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return centreView;
}
```

PS. Some of the TextView i'm referencing arn't needed anymore, I'm just sorting out which ones at the moment.

EDIT: This is what I've ended up with

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView venue;
    TextView time;
    TextView room;
    TextView id;
    TextView dayTV;
    TextView desc;
    TextView json;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    String classNameString;
    String theDate;
    String venueString;
    String idString;
    String description;
    String startTime;
    String endTime;
    String roomString;
    JSONArray alterations;
}
```

and

```
 if (convertView == null) {
        centreView = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi.inflate(resource, centreView, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_name);
        holder.venue = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_venue);
        holder.time = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_time);
        holder.room = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_room);
        holder.id = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_id);
        holder.dayTV = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_day);
        holder.desc = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_description);
        holder.json = (TextView) centreView.findViewById(R.id.class_json);
        holder.jsonObj = items.get(position);
        try {
            holder.classNameString = holder.jsonObj.getString("className");
            holder.theDate = holder.jsonObj.getString("theDate");
            holder.venueString = holder.jsonObj.getString("venue");
            holder.idString = holder.jsonObj.getString("id");
            holder.description = holder.jsonObj.getString("description");
            holder.startTime = holder.jsonObj.getString("startTime");
            holder.endTime = holder.jsonObj.getString("endTime");
            holder.roomString = holder.jsonObj.getString("room");
            holder.alterations = holder.jsonObj.getJSONArray("alteration");
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("FUApp", "JSONError getting details: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        centreView.setTag(holder);
    }
```

Using this my list doesn't lag at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a View Holder

Your code might call `findViewById()` frequently during the scrolling of ListView, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of `findViewById()` is to use the "view holder" design pattern.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

You can initialize Layout Infalter in the constructor of your Adapter class

Edit:

```
 ViewHolder holder;
 if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayouttoinflate, null);
    // initialize views like holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewByID(R.id.text);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
  // set text to text view
  holder.text.setText("hi");
 return convertView;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that ViewHolder now.

Comment: I've just setup my ViewHolder, so do I just reference each item by holder.myView.doSomething()?

Comment: @TomHart you need to initialice view holder object. then use the same to initialize yours textviews and others views. I will update my answer

Comment: @TomHart does it work ? do you see any improvement in performance?

Comment: I've just got a few other bit of work to do first, I'll try this in about an hour, I'll let you know my results then.

Comment: It seem to be smoother now when scrolling really fast. I'm still getting some GC issues "
09-06 12:56:50.065  18499-18503/com.sivltd.fitnessunlimited D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2034K, 40% free 6605K/10876K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 36ms" but that might just be because a fair amount is going on in getView

Comment: @TomHart those are just pause times. Until run into memory leaks you shouldn't worry too much about it. The gc kicks in when it need to free memory. Do check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: I'll take a look at that later on when I get home. Check my post, I've put what I'm using now and it's much smoother and a lot quicker. Thank for the tip on using a ViewHolder :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like the best way. A listview will call getView on all item which aren't display to the screen even they were already created before.
Thanks to these lines :

```
   if (convertView == null) {
    centreView = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    LayoutInflater vi;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vi.inflate(resource, centreView, true);
}
```

Your views aren't created again.
I think you do the best you could for this part.

There is also the viewHolder pattern to store datas efficiently but I never used it. ;).